# Regex in ANTLR4

Tags: regex, antlr4

I want to generate strings like these:

```
tablename(attr1, attr2)    
tablename(attr1, attr2, attr3)
tablename(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)
```

The problem is that with the wildcards operators (*,?,+) I cannot control the cardinality I want, because I need **at least two**.
So, strings like this one are not accepted:

```
tablename(attr1)
tablename()
```

Moreover, I want to reproduce also the commas but not for the last attribute.
Is there a way to do it ANTLR4?

Answer (score 1):

Formulate the possible variantions explicitly. For instance:

```
table: id OPEN_PAR attribute CLOSE_PAR
       | id OPEN_PAR attribute COMMA attribute CLOSE_PAR
       | id OPEN_PAR attribute COMMA attribute COMMA attribute CLOSE_PAR
       | id OPEN_PAR attribute COMMA attribute COMMA attribute COMMA attribute CLOSE_PAR
       ... etc.
;
```